# Using directive & scope

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, namespaces, name-lookup

I have a problem with the folowing code :

```cpp
struct A
{
    A(int i) {};
};

namespace Foo
{
using Alias = A;
}

struct B : Foo::Alias
{
    B();
};

B::B() : Alias(5)
{}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile because in the B constructor, I don't precise the scope of Alias.

Why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, don't you have to use the fully qualified name when `A` is not a template? I thought it'd fail in the same way.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're right : it fails the same way.

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Namespaces) on the namespace page:

> **inline**(optional) **namespace** *attr*(optional) *identifier* {
> *namespace-body* }

> The *namespace-body* defines a [namespace scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope), which affects [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup).
> All names introduced by the declarations that appear within
> namespace-body (including nested namespace definitions) become members
> of the namespace identifier, whether this namespace definition is the
> original namespace definition (which introduced identifier), or an
> extension namespace definition (which "reopened" the already defined
> namespace)

So, based on what the standard has mentioned, whatever is defined inside the namespace as *namespace-body*, is considered at the scope of that namespace and [qualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) applies while referring to anything inside the namespace.